# Set countif / countifs range to ONLY the last row in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the number of times a certain text string appears on the last inspection of a vehicle.  The columns are areas to check, and each inspection is on a separate row.  The range is D6:VG150 (the 150 is to allow for future inspections).  The majority of cells are blank, either because I haven't used that row yet, or there was no fault found in that area during a previous inspection.  The only column that will be filled is column A, which has the dates of inspection. I ONLY want results from the last inspection (to indicate current status on a fleet status worksheet).  Even better would be to check the last filled cell in every column in that range, but that might be pushing it.

I have tried `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'291'!$D$6:$VG"&INDEX(MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))),1)),"Schedule Repair")`, but it returned the results from the entire range defined by the last range.  I tried switching the first address of the range, $D$6, to $D&, but this returned a #REF! error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to simplify your scenario. The screenshot below shows a table that starts in row 3 and extends to row 7. The formula counts how many cells in the last row of the table have the text "a". The formula is

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)+2):INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(A:A)+2),"a")
```

You don't need Indirec. Index is a lot better. The first Index returns the cell A7. The second Index returns the cell C7. Using the colon as the operator will turn the two cells into a range that can then be used by Countif.

The last row is identified by counting all cells with text in column A, and then adjusting for the fact that there are empty rows above the table.

[image]

Oh, and by the way, if you use an Excel Table, you don't need to pre-fill formulas into empty rows. In an Excel Table all formulas are automatically applied to new rows.